# Meaning of "take"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, nouns, slang

Context ([New York Times](http://travel.nytimes.com/2010/04/25/travel/25hours.html)),

> Today, sampling the cuisine can be a rarefied and pricey experience; meals at Michelin-starred kaiseki restaurants like Kikunoi (kikunoi.jp/english) run upward of $160 a person. But for an unbuttoned — and surprisingly affordable — **take** on kaiseki, try Giro Giro Hitoshina...

At first, I thought *take* here is used  as a noun, which is from its verb sense  -- as you know, when *take* is used as a verb, it can be paired up with certain foods, drinks, etc., for example, *take a drink*, *take a meal*.  But it seems *take* also has the sense of, see [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/take),

> 7.Slang An attempt or a try: He got the answer on the third take.

Do you think that *take* means *try* in this context?

Comment: "taking a meal" is not at all common to all dialects of English, although "taking a drink" is pretty standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: *[Take](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take)* also means *an opinion or assessment*, though this article intends the meaning *sampling*.

Elaboration: Usually *take* is followed by "on", then followed by whatever the opinion is about (e.g. *What's your take on the candidate?*), and is rarely used otherwise in this sense.  However, this article's usage is rather awkward, since *opinion* here is ambiguous; it sounds as if you are asking a master chef for his opinion, rather than (as it actually means) forming your own opinion by tasting the restaurant's food.  *Sampling* might be a better word here:

> To get an unbuttoned — and surprisingly affordable — sampling of [this Japanese food], try [this restaurant].

Comment: In this context, the "opinion" is somewhat metaphorical: by offering you kaiseki prepared in a specific way, the chef is implicitly making a claim about how kaiseki should be served.

Answer (score 1):

"Take" here is an idiomatic usage, and it means "perspective, approach, aesthetic".

I believe it was adopted from the film industry, where a "take" is a particular way of filming a scene, and then other "takes" would be shot, from which a final scene would be edited up out of the various perspectives and shooting angles.

Thus, "your take" on a particular problem or scene might well be quite different from "my take" of the same scene, because you -- as the cinematographer -- would choose a different shooting angle, perhaps zoom in close from quite far away, etc.

So just as different cameramen and cinematographers might shoot the same scene in various "takes", "your take" on a sushi restaurant would be your realization of how you think a sushi restaurant should be, whereas "my take" might be a much different perspective or aesthetic.

Answer (score 0):

Far as I can tell, take means 'sample' in this context. And its used in the sense of "To acquire a sufficient familiarity with something so as to have a definite opinion about the thing"